# Overriding Webpack 4 Entry Point

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, entry-point

Here's the directory of my project:

```
   -node_modules
   -src
       -client
          -js
          -styles
          -views
          -index.js
          -webpack.config.js
       -server
   -.babelrc
   -package
   -package-lock
   -README.md
   -webpack.dev
   -webpack.prod
```

Here's the content of my **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'none',
    //entry: path.resolve(__dirname) + './src/client/index.js',

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: '/\.js$./',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to override the default entry point inside webpack.config.js to point to the **index.js** file in the same level.

By default, if I have the index.js file inside the **src** directory, without specifying the entry point, it works as expected.

I have tried changing the entry points like this:

`entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client/index.js'),`

`entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + 'client/index.js',`

`entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),`

`entry: path.resolve(__dirname) + '/src/client/index.js',`

`entry: path.resolve(__dirname) + './src/client/index.js'`

I'm using a windows 10 Operating System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js'
};
```

Ref: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/

---

Alternatively, you can also use

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: require.resolve('./index')
};
```

Ref: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options

Comment: With this, it's not able to resolve the entry file as I got this error:

 ```ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\***\Projects\***\***\***'```

Comment: Does not seem like there is anything wrong with webpack enrty point. Could be possible the path used somewhere else in you webpack or any node module you're using has src in it which is not getting resolved. Not sure.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I started off listing the files in my directory and showing where the **index.js** is in reference to the **webpack.config.js**.

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem was to move the `webpack.config.js` file to the root folder and then configured the entry point like this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...    
    entry: './src/client/index.js',
    ...
}
```