# I can't make a new entry point for webpack because of the path error

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, entry-point

I'm following a beginner course in webpack. I'm trying to change the default entry point to a new path which is `./src/client/index.js` but it gives me an error 
[image]

I searched on the error and did the suggested answer to make the path starts with `../src` but it gives the same error .also this answer [override default entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58915153/overriding-webpack-4-entry-point) but the same error. could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?
also, I don't know if it is relevant but I was inside my main project folder when I opened the cmd.

webpack.config.js

```
// Allows us to override the default configs that come with webpack
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    //webpack is going to start build our tree from
    entry:'./src/client/index.js',
}
```

I added "build":"webpack" to package.jason

[image]

Comment: You have 3 `webpack.config` files. Which one are you using? The one inside the `client` directory probably should move to the root directory.

Comment: the root as adding webpack.config.js at the same level as src folder ?

Comment: Yes. Next to your `package.json` file. You probably should not have 3 config files regardless. Or you can change the `build` command to `webpack --config=./src/webpack.config.js`.